# I want to retrieve emails from gmail account with the body using imap in python

Tags: python-2.7, imap, gmail-imap

This is my code and m trying to get the emails from gmail with the body but it end with the error.
" mail = email.message_from_string(data[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1sZp.png))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message_from_string'"
Any help is appriciated!.
[the error message is being shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1sZp.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import getpass
import imaplib
import email
from email.parser import HeaderParser

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
email = raw_input("Email address: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
M.login(email, password)

M.select()
resp, data = M.FETCH(1, '(RFC822)')
mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

for part in mail.walk():
  # multipart are just containers, so we skip them
  if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
      continue

  # we are interested only in the simple text messages
  if part.get_content_subtype() != 'plain':
    continue

  payload = part.get_payload()
  print payload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overwritten the "email" module with a string you've inputted from the user.

```
import email
...
email = raw_input("Email address: ")
...
mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
```

Change the line `email = raw_input("Email address: ")` to some other name, such as `address = raw_input("Email address: ")` and adjust your code as required.

Comment: Thanx max for your help it was useful.

Comment: Please accept this answer if this has fixed your error.  open another question if you have a different question.

Comment: what shall i do if i want to get all the mails present in the mailbox

Comment: You should open another question.  This one (fixing your 'email' error) has been addressed.